# Is 'ruffle' used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

- The opposing team jeered at us while we walked onto the field, but we did not let their comments *ruffle* our confidence.

Comment: "Composure" might pair better with "ruffle" than "confidence".

Comment: What @user888379 said. [***Composure is ruffled, confidence is dented***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ruffled+his+composure%2Cruffled+his+confidence%2Cdented+his+composure%2Cdented+his+confidence&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cruffled%20his%20composure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdented%20his%20confidence%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The other option is to go with the metaphor: ruffle our feathers

Answer (score 2):

The usual verb you are probably searching for is **rattle**.

Google ngram searches for *ruffle our confidence, ruffled our confidence*, and *ruffled their confidence* produce flatlines, while **[rattled their confidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rattled+their+confidence&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crattled%20their%20confidence%3B%2Cc0)** is in obvious use.

[image]

This is reflected in raw Google searches.

- "ruffle our confidence": 9
- "ruffled our confidence": 3
- "ruffle their confidence": 3
- "rattle their confidence": 65 000
- "rattled our confidence": 37 000

This though the words 'rattle' and 'ruffle' are synonyms meaning fluster ... unnerve, when used with a person as DO. Only 'rattle' has apparently broadened to accept related DOs such as 'confidence', 'composure'. Probably 'rattle' is more drastic; '*shook* their confidence' is, according to raw Google data, far more idiomatic.

Comment: Should that be "confidence" rather than "conscience" in those bulleted items?

Comment: Thanks dude lol

Comment: I am most used to **composure** getting rattled.

Comment: I'd just come up with that as a second non-person DO. It's not as strong a collocate as 'confidence'.

Comment: Just ***people*** are normally ***rattled***. Their ***confidence*** is [more likely to be ***dented***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dented+his+confidence%2Crattled+his+confidence&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdented%20his%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crattled%20his%20confidence%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: And even more likely to be [{as per Google ngrams} shattered or shaken](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dented+his+confidence%2Crattled+his+confidence%2Cshattered+his+confidence%2Cshook+his+confidence&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdented%20his%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crattled%20his%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshattered%20his%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshook%20his%20confidence%3B%2Cc0).